# Does 2 one-dimensional intervals touch?

Tags: computational-mathematics, integers

As the title mentions I have 2 one-dimensional intervals given like so:

$[a, a-b]$
$[x, x-y]$

where $a$ and $x$ are the start points, and $b$ and $y$ are the length of the intervals.

The intervals are given in integers (and within the interval 0-9). What I need to find out is the best way to making sure $[x, x-y]$ does not even touch $[a, a-b]$. This includes the integers at both ends which implies that:

$$a\neq x$$
$$a\neq x-y$$
$$x\neq a-b$$
$$x-y\neq a-b$$

A graphical way of showing it: 
**Should be true**
[image: Good intervals]

**Should be false**
[image: Bad intervals]

Comment: What happens if $x\le a+b?$ What if $x>a+b?$

Comment: @mfl The length only goes to the left side from the start point so those are irrelevant.

Comment: Intervals are usually written $[a,b]$ with $a<b$. The notation $[a,a-b]$ is quite confusing, prefer $[a-b,a]$.

Comment: Could you write what $a$ is in each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the notation $[a,b]$ for the interval that includes all the numbers between $a$ and $b$, inclusive.  (I think you are using $[a, a-b]$ for the same thing.)

It's easy to see that if the intervals $[a,b]$ and $[x,y]$ *do not* overlap then one of them must be entirely to the left of the other.  For this to happen, one must have either $b < x$ (if the first interval is on the left) or $y < a$ (if the second is on the left).

So the intervals *do not* overlap if

$$b < x\text{ or } y < a$$

and therefore they *do overlap* if

$$b \ge x \text { and } y \ge a.$$